# Zend 1 ajax with dojo informatiom person

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, dojo

I'm working with Zend 1 with dojo and do not know how to use ajax . In my particular case that when selecting a select , whether made ​​in consultation ajax back from the database information. To enter a ID from user print the information from user by ajax.In my work I can't use jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question!
Not is very productive work with dojo, but is possible make exactly how do you want. You will create p element with information captured in data base

In your form, add attribute 'onChange'

```
$form->setAttrib('onChange', 'recoveryData()');
```

In js file do you have a function recoveryData(), something as:

```
dojo.require("dojo.html");

// clean data
var myNewElement = dojo.byId('myNewElement');
if (myNewElement != null) { 
    dojo.empty("myNewElement"); 
}

dojo.xhrPost({
    content: {id: dojo.attr(dojo.byId("myElement"), "value")},
    url: 'your-base-path/recovery-data/',
    load: function (response) {
        if (response != false) {
            // converte to obj
            var obj = dojo.fromJson(response);

            // creat new element
            var node = dojo.create("span", {
                    innerHTML: obj.NomeServidor,
                    id: "myNewElement",
                    'class': 'row'
                }
            );
            dojo.place(node, dojo.byId("myElement"), "after");
        }
    }
});
```

Now, you need create an Action "recoveryDataAction()" in your Controller like this:

```
$data = $this->getrequest()->getPost();
$id = $data['id'];
if ($this->getrequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    // disable layout
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    // disable view render
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    $yourTable = new Project_Model_YourTable();
    $row = $yourTable->fetchRow($id);
    if ($infos != null) {
        echo Zend_Json::encode($row);
        return;
    }
    echo false;
}
```